# Split a string containing digits

Tags: c#

I'm having a string like,

```
"abc kskd 8.900 prew"
```

need to `Split` this string so that i get the result as `"abc kskd"` and `"8.900 prew"`

how can i achieve this with `C#`?

Comment: space immediately preceeding the first number in the string

Comment: @user3085995 Try providing some more examples of expected input/output and some code of what you have attempted so far.

Comment: You're likely to receive answers that don't actually do what you want, because what you want is only vaguely explained. Are you wanting to split the string into sets of two words or numbers? Are you wanting to split the string into "everything before the first number" and "the first number and every that follows"? Are you wanting to split the string into "everything before the first number", "the first number and what follows up to the second number", "the second number and what follows up to..." and so on? All of these fit with what you've written, so people will have to guess what you mean.

Comment: @Chris: i need two strings,first one is the string before any digits and the second one is the remaining string with digits

Comment: Selman22's answer seems to do what you want, in that case. Find the index of the first digit, then use that to split the string into two parts based on the index. It may be more complex though if you could potentially have digits *embedded in* the initial words and you don't want those digits to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

straightforward with a regular expression:

```
var str = "abc kskd 8.900 prew";
var result = Regex.Split(str, @"\W(\d.*)").Where(x => x!="").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the index of first digit using `LINQ` then use `Substring`:

```
var input = "abc kskd 8.900 prew";
var index = input.Select( (x,idx) => new {x, idx})
           .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c.x))
           .Select(c => c.idx)
           .First();

var part1 = input.Substring(0, index);
var part2 = input.Substring(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do if you don't need to do something complicated:

```
var data = "abc kskd 8.900 prew";
var digits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();

var idx = data.IndexOfAny(digits);

if (idx != -1)
{
  var firstPart = data.Substring(0, idx - 1);
  var secondPart = data.Substring(idx);
}
```

`IndexOfAny` is actually very fast.

This could also be modified to separate the string into more parts (using the `startIndex` parameter), but you didn't ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public string[] SplitText(string text)
{
var startIndex = 0;
while (startIndex < text.Length)
{
    var index = text.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray(), startIndex);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    var spaceIndex = text.LastIndexOf(' ', startIndex, index - startIndex);
    if (spaceIndex != 0)
    {
        return new String[] { text.Substring(0, spaceIndex), text.Substring(spaceIndex + 1) };
    }

    startIndex = index;
}

return new String[] {text};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what [@Dominic Kexel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22687175/2294202) provided, but only if you don't want to use linq.

```cs
string[] result = Regex.Split("abc kskd 8.900 prew", @"\w*(?=\d+\.\d)");
```

Comment: not quite the same: the first element of your result array contains an extra whitespace at the end, which should be removed (`abc kskd ` vs. `abc kskd`).

Comment: @DominicKexel you are right. I did not notice that. Then you would have to use `Trim`on the first element.